# Why does it return null instead of value?

Tags: mongodb

```
> db.patients.findOne()
```

{
"_id" : ObjectId("603fc797f0af296be54caecc"),
"name" : "Fahim ",
"age" : 29,
"diseaseSummary" : "f_26_ds "
}

> db.diseaseSummary.findOne()
> { "_id" : "f_26_ds", "diseases" : [ "fever ", "cough ", "corona " ] }
> var dsd = db.patients.findOne().diseaseSummary
> dsd
> f_26_ds
> db.diseaseSummary.findOne({_id: dsd } )
> null

```js
> db.patients.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("603fc797f0af296be54caecc"),
        "name" : "Fahim ",
        "age" : 29,
        "diseaseSummary" : "f_26_ds "
}
> db.diseaseSummary.findOne()
{ "_id" : "f_26_ds", "diseases" : [ "fever ", "cough ", "corona " ] }
> var dsd = db.patients.findOne().diseaseSummary
> dsd
f_26_ds
> db.diseaseSummary.findOne({_id: dsd } )
null
> ?????? why "null" comes
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more your question,what are you doing (code, just functions on terminal...), what are you trying to get, what you are getting, are you using any npm package? (mongoose for example). From what i can see you are trying to use one variable storing a value as the id parameter of find, right?

Comment: Sir, actually I am learning mongodb and here  declare a variable and store the query result then i pass the result to math id . after match i want fetch the data by the id

Comment: You have a typo in the data - the `diseaseSummary` in the `patients` collection has a trailing space.